# Custom Python Nodes: Calling Group Node

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, materials, node-editor

I am writing a custom shader node that essentially "Calls" a predefined group node into the code.

Here is the group node I am looking to call:

[image: Custom Fresnel V2 Node]

I am using the "CustomNode" template that is packaged within Blender's text editor. All I want to do is add this pre-defined group into my new CustomNode. How do I go about doing this?